# Questioning the category of the “moral”

Tags: ethics, modal-logic, deconstruction, cognition

Briefly: it occurs to me that taking as given the pre-existence of the terms “morality” and “ethics” structures our thinking preemptively and heavily. In the manner of discursive analysts like Nietzsche and Derrida, one may wonder to what extent we are trapped in a conceptual bubble, assuming the existence of such a thing, while trying to define and justify it.

I am curious what philosophers have questioned this category altogether, especially recent philosophers, and maybe offered a cousin concept that overlaps with some of its ideas.

I suggest the field of “deontics”. Deontic modality is the most abstract formulation I can think of of the extremely general cognitive ability to consider what *should* be, in one way or another. I think it is very likely that this attribute of cognition and consciousness is so general that it would not at all be distinctive to humans but would occur in possibly any entity attaining a certain level of mental “being”, sentience, etc.

Comment: It is not the *"pre-existence of the terms “morality” and “ethics"* that *"structures our thinking preemptively and heavily."* it is the *"pre-existence"* of what those terms denote that, *"structures our thinking preemptively and heavily."*, terms are more like signs less like symbols, the pre-existence of what a symbol denotes defines the existence of the sign (i.e., semiotic entity), think of it as the difference between Sumer (Cuneiform) & Egypt (Hieroglyphs), hence why it is difficult to conceptualize things like "Where do rights come from?" (see: *Man and His Symbols* by Carl Jung)

Answer (score 2):

**Original**

Baruch Spinoza, in The Ethics, describes affect (emotion) as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. Notice there is no distinction in this terse description between a moral source of cause and some other non-moral source of cause. The self and others are described as ideas of cause without reference to moral classification as moral agents. But Spinoza says love is pleasure accompanied by an idea of its cause and contempt or hatred is pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. Moral and ethical sentiments would then arise as products of the process of forming emotions in this context.

Sigmund Freud, the founder of psychoanalysis, describes the ego as the part of a biological organism that, in response to an impulse, can act or inhibit action. The biological ego, which makes efforts to govern action in the sensory context, is not described as moral or non-moral. Moral and ethical sentiments in Freud's ego-development model arise when the newborn ego interacts with and recognizes external egos: parents and adults in the social group. Freud maps the transformation of the non-moral ego to a domain of moral and ethical social memories called the superego.

If we perform neural experiments or autopsies then there is no means to locate the exact places in the nervous system where one finds the qualia or perceptions called pleasure, pain, ideas of cause, moral agents, or ethical evaluations. The nervous system integrated within the body is recognized as a structure that performs biological cognitive functions. Humans operate in the world of human affairs as if there is a mind in each body and a body in each mind with moral and ethical attributes.

**Edit**

SEP - Behaviorism

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/behaviorism/

Behaviorism is a theory in psychology which holds that the biological organism responds to stimuli in the surroundings and to memories of past stimuli that condition responses to present stimuli. This type of analysis abstracts away from moral and ethical sentiments, and in the more extreme form, denies that mental states influence animal or human behavior. This discounts, ignores, and attempts to erase the discussion of moral and ethical concerns in the context of analyzing patterns of behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If one wants to make a distinction between *moral* and *ethics*, then *moral* is the system of rules and values established or requested at a certain time in a given society. While *ethics* or *morality* is the philosophical investigation of different types of morals. In particular to argue in favour or against certain morals.

Moreover:

> In *deontological ethics* an action is considered morally good because
> of some characteristic of the action itself, not because the product
> of the action is good,

see Britannica [deontological-ethics](https://www.britannica.com/topic/deontological-ethics). For an introduction see [Deontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontology), and more advanced SEP [deontological ethics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-deontological/).

While *deontic logic* is a field of logic which formalizes logical concepts like permission, obligation, prohibition.

Your proposal to replace the terms *moraliy* or *ethics* by *deontics* would restrict the present meaning of these concepts and introduce a word which is prone to be mixed up with similar words.
Hence I do not see any benefit to replace the original concepts by the new word *deontics*.

Moreover, I do not see that you introduce a new category at all. To me it looks more like a linguistic proposal.

Answer (score -1):

You suggest that the labels ethics and morals condition our thinking. It seems much more likely to me that our thinking is conditioned by the centuries of baggage to which the labels are attached.